# linux: package for specific "command history" on terminal line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, script, terminal

Is there a package I can download for Ubuntu that would allow me to type in,for example, cd [tab key] and then it would go through the recent cd commands I've typed in?

Comment: Is the question _only_ about `cd`? In that case I would recommend making aliases for `pushd` and `popd`.

Answer (score 2):

If you type:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> cd

Then scroll back through time by doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> again and again...

then it should do what you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks.  Just what I needed.  It would be better if you could just use tab, but I'm sure I could just code it myself while I'm playing around with the linux source code anyways.  Thanks again.

Comment: Keep in mind that this does not apply to every possible shell.  But this is possible on the default shell (bash).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't this option, but the most used Linux have a package called bash_completion that extends the TAB function.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/bash-completion